# How to get the shape of a xarray dataset by using dims labels

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there a more elegant way than this to get a tuple of the shape of some dimensions of an [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) dataset?

```
tuple(dict(ds[['X', 'Y']].dims).values())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `xarray.Dataset`, you can do this:

```
tuple(ds.dims[d] for d in ['X', 'Y'])
```

This has the advantage of not subsetting the dataset or relying on the dimensions to be coordinates as well.

Comment: Thank you! `ds.dims['X']` is what I needed. Not sure why that is so complicated